# Exchange Web Services update email as read does not work C#

Tags: c#, sql, email, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I'm using Exchange Web Services to read email from exchange server and update it. I have an account with a parent email with subfolders in inbox, I can read the email I want successfully, but when I try to mark it as read it does not work, the email remains unread.

There is my code:

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var exchange = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2013_SP1);
        exchange.Credentials = new WebCredentials("User", "Pass", "Domain");
        exchange.AutodiscoverUrl("Email", RedirectionCallback);
        FolderId folderToAccess = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, "ParentEmail");
        FolderView view2 = new FolderView(100);
        view2.PropertySet = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.IdOnly);
        view2.PropertySet.Add(FolderSchema.DisplayName);
        view2.Traversal = FolderTraversal.Deep;
        FindFoldersResults findFolderResults = exchange.FindFolders(folderToAccess, view2).Result;

        foreach (Folder f in findFolderResults)
        {
            if (f.DisplayName == "NameOfTheFolderUnderInbox")
            {
                var SearchFilter = new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(EmailMessageSchema.IsRead, false);
                ItemView view = new ItemView(100);
                FindItemsResults<Item> findResults = exchange.FindItems(f.Id, SearchFilter, view).Result;

                foreach (Item item in findResults)
                {
                    PropertySet props = new PropertySet(EmailMessageSchema.MimeContent, ItemSchema.Subject);
                    EmailMessage message = EmailMessage.Bind(exchange, item.Id, props).Result;
                    if (message.Subject.Contains("Text"))
                    {
                        string emlFileName = @"C:\export\email.eml";
                        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(emlFileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
                        {
                            fs.Write(message.MimeContent.Content, 0, message.MimeContent.Content.Length);
                        }
                    }
                    message.IsRead = true;
                    message.Update(ConflictResolutionMode.AlwaysOverwrite, true);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    static bool RedirectionCallback(string url)
    {
        // Return true if the URL is an HTTPS URL.
        return url.ToLower().StartsWith("https://");
    }
```

Comment: `email remains unread`: how did you check? Did you close Outlook before running this program, and re-open it after running this program, than you did it correct, Outlook likes to cache this kind of info somehow/somewhere...

Comment: Yes, I closed it then started it again, before and after the program. And if I run it again, the email is still unread....I'm going crazy for that.

Comment: If you do a message.load() after the update what is the property value for IsRead ?

Comment: IsRead = true, but on outlook still unread.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved the problem and maybe could be usefull for someone else.

After the update, making a new research the email went read also on outlook.

```
FindItemsResults<Item> UpdateResults = exchange.FindItems(f.Id, SearchFilter, view).Result
```

This after update make it work!